# How do I get the title of a .pdf document to appear as the page title?

Tags: html, pdf

I'm posting a PDF at a website and have a link pointing to it, the same as any other file. If the browser is capable, it displays the PDF in a new tab. But the URL (and an unwieldy one at that) is showing up on the top of the tab where the document `title` usually goes. Do PDF files have a parameter for this I can adjust? Or is there a way to wrap the file in something that does?

(I've tried checking "display document title" in Acrobat's options, that doesn't do it.)

Comment: I suppose this'll largely depend on the browser/plugin displaying the PDF and is either not possible at all or not consistently. Not a PDF expert though, hence comment only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is something you can control within the PDF itself.  It's controlled by the web app serving the PDF, and your browser's PDF plugin, which will most likely just use the PDF's URL as the `<title>`.  The filename of the served PDF can specified by the web app by setting a *content-disposition* header in the HTTP response, but again this isn't something you can control.

Answer (score 2):

The text that is displayed in the browser tab has nothing to do with the PDF -- other than it's the URL of the PDF. That info you're seeing is controlled by the web page and by the browser. You cannot change it by making any changes to the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title, however, from my quick research, how you create the PDF is important. Using a Windows 10 laptop I printed the PDF using Microsoft Print to PDF. Next, I opened the PDF in NotePad++ and searched for "title". I renamed the title and saved. Although I have paid copy of Acrobat DC, the title change using "Acrobat PDF", the remaning steps did not work.

I found the solution on YouTube:

How to Change the PDF Title that appears in a web browser (using free software)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJw77is-f50